# ActiveSupport::Concern missing super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have a class GoodsTransaction:

```
require Rails.root.join('lib','two_parties_transaction.rb')

class GoodsTransaction < Transaction

  include TwoPartiesTransaction

  def counterparty(org, loop = false)

    res = #Some logic
    res || super(org)
  end
end
```

which includes the TwoPartiesTransaction module:

```
module TwoPartiesTransaction
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def counterparty(org)
       #Some logic
    end
  end
end
```

and running counterparty fails:

```
muichkine@ubuntu:~/src/white$ rails c
Faraday::Builder is now Faraday::RackBuilder.
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0p247 :001 > tr = GoodsTransaction.new
=> #<GoodsTransaction _id: 5264e2eb75627540dd000000, e(end_date): nil, p(span): nil, s(start_date): nil, u(span_unit): nil, _type: "GoodsTransaction", a(autobook): nil, c(forced_close): nil, d(public_id): nil, k(autobook_period): nil, l(label): nil, n(autobook_number): nil, t(autobook_until): nil, contact_ids: nil, parent_id: nil, fc(creditor): nil, fd(debtor): nil> 
2.0.0p247 :002 > tr.counterparty(nil)
NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `counterparty' for   #<GoodsTransaction:0x000000090fe1d8>
from /home/muichkine/src/white/app/models/transactions/goods_transaction.rb:148:in `counterparty'
```

What am I doing that skips the super coutnerparty method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For including instance methods from the module into a class, you do not need to use `ActiveSupport::Concern`. You can just do

```
module TwoPartiesTransaction
  def counterparty(org)
     # ...
  end
end
```

You can still use `ActiveSupport::Concern` if you need it for other reasons, namely executing code at the class level (such as `scope` etc.) or adding class methods to the including class. For more detail on `ActiveSupport::Concern`, [see the API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Comment: From the documentation you point to I understand that 1/ ClassMethods are extended not included into base class, which is not what I'm looking at. 2/ The documentation does not talk at all about ClassMethods being mandatory, as they place code directly inside the `indluded do` block. Am I wrong on this?!

Comment: 1) I agree it's confusing but `extend` will add the instance methods of the module as class methods. Isn't that what you want? 2) i have edited my answer, maybe that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: If you should happen to want the module methods as instance methods in the class including the module, just use plain methods in the module (not in the nested `ClassMethods`)

Comment: Well, 1/ I want indeed instance methods so I agree putting them in ClassMethods makes no sense. 2/Your code makes no use of the included do block, which from what I understand is the basic principle of ActiveSupport::Concern. 3/Putting code directly inside the module without the included do raises errors since the code is evaluated at loading time instead of at include time.

Comment: Ok now the answer to your question is rather simple. Please see my edit.

Comment: OK, I understand. Here is the full answer for anyone to see. Code inserted inside the include do is actually added in the base class. So if base class implements a method of the same signature, it is being replaced, hence there is indeed no super method. One should only write in the included do the code that requires dependencies such as ActiveRecord / MongoID code. Plain ruby methods should be written as p11y wrote: outside included do block.